Unity physics is applied on objects that use XRGrabInteractable
I have a script that creates primitive spheres, I want them to be interactable in vr using XRGrabInteractable or any other component, whenever I do this:
grabInteractable = sphereObject.AddComponent<XRGrabInteractable>();

for some reason the spheres start having gravity and fall on the ground, meaning they also have collision

Can you please provide us the code of XRGrabInteractable or more informations?
